# iPad Icon names?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Do I have to put 2 icon images in my build for iPad? and what are the names of those 2 build, one is Icon.png and what is the other one?

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [*iPhone* apps](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) you need to provide a 57x57 `Icon.png` and may optionally provide a 29x29 `Icon-Small.png`.

To submit to AppStore you need a 512x512 icon too.

There's no special requirement for iPad. A 57x57 `Icon.png` is sufficient. Although you can add a larger 72x72 icon and add it into the `CFBundleIconFiles` key. (See [How do I specify both icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app).)

Answer (score 4):

The default name for an iPad icon is `Icon-72.png`. You do not currently need two icons for iPad submissions, though there are in fact a dozen other icon sizes that a “complete” app should contain.

Comment: Just a heads up, my app did not pass verification without the `Icon-72.png` as of this morning. Also, the capitalization does matter.