# Is it possible to make my iPhone app's icon look correct on both the iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons

Our CEO wants our iPhone app's icons to look correct (ie not scaled) on both the iPad and iPhone.  He does not want to actually create separate versions, or a universal version of the app.  The app will remain iPhone only, but the icon would need to show up proper on both devices.

This is a "business decision", and I think its rather silly but regardless - is this possible?  OR would we have to create a universal version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You have to create all the 72x72 (iPad), 57x57 (iPhone) and 29x29 (Settings, if you have one) icons, if you(r boss) don't want scaling.

And you need to create a 512x512 version to submit to AppStore anyway, so I don't see a reason to avoid an extra image.

To use the 72x72 icon for iPad, see [How do I specify both icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app).

Comment: iPhone icons are 57x57 (not 59x60)