# Is CFBundleIconFiles the same as Icon File?

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, retina-display

I am trying to add a hi-res icon to my iPhone app. Is Is CFBundleIconFiles the same as Icon File in the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following question on Stack Overflow, this should clear things up:

[How do I specify both icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app)

In short, no it's not the same. The Icon File setting is the pre-iOS4 setting, but you should keep this for iOS3 compatibility if you allow your app to install on iOS3. The Icon File setting should point to the 57x57 sized icon.

iOS4 uses the Icon Files setting, which is actually an array containing all filenames of all the icons. It scans through all the specified icons and uses the one with the closest matching size for the job. You should add your high resolution icon to this list as well as the standard 57x57 icon.

Answer (score 2):

As Yannick pointed out, 'CFBundleIconFiles' is not the same as 'Icon Files', but there is another relation:

'Icon File' is the Xcode name for the key 'CFBundleIconFile' and
'Icon Files' is the Xcode name for the key 'CFBundleIconFiles'.

So those are equivalent. See [Apple's Core Foundation Keys Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1).