# How to have icons for ipad and iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, icons

I dont get it :) I have an Icon.pn that is currently 57x57, but when I compile I get a warning that it needs to be 72x72. If I make it 72x72 it complains that it needs to be 57x57.

I do understand the problem but I do not know how to solve it, how can I tell xcode which icon is for which device ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify both icons for a universal iPhone/iPad app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide a list of icons in your Info.plist.  However, the iTunes Connect validation process currently won't recognize the iPad icon unless you call it out specifically.  For example, the following will indicate icons for iPhone, Retina display iPhones, and iPad:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>MyAppIcon.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>MyAppIcon@2x.png</string>
    <string>MyAppIcon.png</string>
    <string>MyAppIcon72.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>MyAppIcon72.png</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your info.plist file, add a property with the type array and put both files in.

[image]